# Proof of solvability of B2 group

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

I am trying to understand the following proof of solvability for the group $B_2$.

Let $B_2 = \{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\&d\end{pmatrix}:ad\in\Re^x, b\in\Re\}$

Let $U_2 = \{\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\&1\end{pmatrix}:b\in\Re\}$

$U_2$ normal subgroup as it is the kernel of $f:B_2\rightarrow\Re^x\times\Re^x$ defined as follows:

$f(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\&d\end{pmatrix})=(a,d)$

$Ker(f)$ solvable since $U_2$ is nilpotent/abelian

$Im(f)$ commutative since its isomorphic to $\Re^x\times\Re^x$

But why do these two facts about the kernel and image of $f$ imply that $B_2$ is solvable?